# Angular multi attribute on select tag alters the value of the option tags

Tags: javascript, html, angular, tags

When I use a multiple attribute on the select tag, Angular alters the value of the option tags. for instance:

```
this.options = [
  { id: 1, name: 'me' },
  { id: 2, name: 'you' }
];

<select [(ngModel)]="model" multiple>
  <option *ngFor="let o of options" [value]="o.id"> {{o.name}} </option>

</select>
```

Results in =>

```
<option value="0: '1'">me</option>
<option value="1: '2'">you</option>
```

Angular prepends the index of the object in the array to the value of the options tags. Is there anyway to stop this behaviour?

Comment: What is version of angular do you use?

Comment: @Leguest Angular 2.4.5

Comment: That's happen because of `multiple` attribute. So `value="1: '2'"` does not affect on  `[(ngModel)]="model"` it will be `[1,2]` anyway

Comment: @Leguest, I'm aware of that but is there any way to stop that behavior. I need the value to be correct in the DOM

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I ended up with custom `directive`. I called it `multipleNormalize` and used it like `[multipleNormalize]="o.id"`

Typescript

```
import {Directive, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import {Input} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[multipleNormalize]',
})

export class MultipleNormalizeDirective {

    @Input('multipleNormalize') model:any;

    constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.elementRef.nativeElement.value = this.model;
    }


}
```

HTML

```
<select [(ngModel)]="testModel" multiple>
            <option *ngFor="let o of optionItems" [ngValue]="o.id" [multipleNormalize]="o.id">{{o.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It looks working but actually screwd things up later. See the screenshot below.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEIB1.png

Answer (score 0):

Use `[ngValue]` instead of `[value]`.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="model" multiple>
  <option *ngFor="let o of options" [ngValue]="o.id"> {{o.name}} </option>
</select>
```